# winforms - auto refresh gridbox on selected item in another gridbox

Tags: c#

i have 2 different grids
grid A and Grid B, i want that when i press on a row on Grid A so Grid B will show data that relevant to the row in Grid A.

grid a is item list
and its have title lets say pencil
so in grid b i want it will show everyone who holding that pencil (its items and vendors) so i want it will show in grid b all the vendors that have the pencil with all the pencil data (price, description etc.. that relevant for each vendor item)
so it can be that vendor a will have pencil that cost 2$ and vendor b will have pencil that cost 5$

hope its clear enough if now ill upload my code later today
thanks,

Comment: Are you in WinForm or WPF environment, and that you have two datagridviews, right?

Comment: 1. Do you know how to detect clicks on the source DataGrid? 2. Do you know how to get the selected value (pencil Id, Name) from that row? 3. Do you know how to get the associated vendor from value obtained in the previous step? 4. Do you know how to display the values from question 3 in a second DataGrid? Tell us that and we may be able to help, but as of now it would be difficult for us to give an actually relevant/helpful answer as you didn't provide enough details.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply
I don't know how to detect selected row in the grid yet
I used list box until now, and I know to detect the selected row, so I guess its similar to the grid box
i know how to bind data, and how to associate vendor with items